# How to implement an "assert_difference" for ExUnit

Tags: testing, elixir, ex-unit

I'd like to test how a function changes something in the database. I'm struggling with an ExUnit equivalent of the following `ActiveSupport::TestCase` test case:

```ruby
test "creates a database record" do
  post = Post.create title: "See the difference"
  assert_difference "Post.published.count" do
    post.publish!
  end
end
```

The RSpec version is more elegant and, because of its use of lambdas, something I thought was portable to Elixir/ExUnit.

```ruby
it "create a database record" do
  post = Post.create title: "See the difference"
  expect { post.publish! }.to change { Post.count }.by 1
end
```

Is there a more elegant (read: functional) way to do it than this:

```elixir
test "creates a database record", %{conn: conn} do
  records_before = count_records
  post(conn, "/articles")
  records_after  = count_records

  assert records_before == (records_after - 1)
end

defp count_records do
  MyApp.Repo.one((from a in MyApp.Article, select: count("*"))
end
```

Comment: More functional way to detect a `change` (read “to detect an object mutation”) sounds a bit weird to me :) There is no state, objects are all immutable, so the most functional way would be the one you’ve proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use macros to get something close to the TestUnit and RSpec examples from Ruby:

```
defmacro assert_difference(expr, do: block) do
  quote do
    before = unquote(expr)
    unquote(block)
    after_ = unquote(expr)
    assert before != after_
  end
end

defmacro assert_difference(expr, [with: with], do: block) do
  quote do
    before = unquote(expr)
    unquote(block)
    after_ = unquote(expr)
    assert unquote(with).(before) == after_
  end
end

test "the truth" do
  {:ok, agent} = Agent.start_link(fn -> 0 end)

  assert_difference Agent.get(agent, &(&1)) do
    Agent.update(agent, &(&1 + 1))
  end

  {:ok, agent} = Agent.start_link(fn -> 0 end)

  assert_difference Agent.get(agent, &(&1)), with: &(&1 + 2) do
    Agent.update(agent, &(&1 + 2))
  end
end
```

But I wouldn't use it unless it's going to be used a *lot* or else this would only make the code harder to follow for everyone (possibly) except the author. If you do use it though, you might want to move it to a different module and import that in your test modules.

Comment: Thanks! That was also a good learning exercise on Agents for me :)

Comment: this will not work... Tests are run async, so there could be 20 records created in the time between before and after..